# Create multiple Buttons with ClickListener and identify what Button was clicked? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, logic

Think of the Uno Card Game logic for example, how could I get the clicked Card on the players hand, when I create the cards on the players hand dynamically by clicking on a draw button?

something like:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.onclick = () => {
  alert(btnCounter);
}
btnCounter++;
```

but the onclick function should be written once and then be saved for this button.

Comment: Just save a separate binding for `btnCounter` in a different variable?

Comment: Why do you want to do like this only, you can also bind onclick event, if you are dynamically including button in html via JS. Like ```<button onclick='yourFunction()'>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to rely on event bubbling. We can add the event listener to the container for our hand and then, on click, make sure the clicked element was a button. In this example, I put our card's value in the button's dataset, but you can grab the info from anywhere on the target.

```js
const hand = document.querySelector("#hand");

hand.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName !== "BUTTON") return;
  console.log(e.target.dataset.card);
});

function drawCards(numberOfCards) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    const card = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    button.setAttribute("data-card", card);
    button.innerHTML = card;
    hand.appendChild(button);
  }
};

drawCards(5);
```

```html
<div id="hand"></div>
```

Comment: but if I go for hand.removeChild(hand.childNodes[click.target.dataset.card]); the indexing seems to be messed up, how could I remove elements and reindex the buttons?

Comment: Do you want to remove the child on click? Basically the same time it's being logged in my example?

Comment: If so, you can just do `e.target.remove()`!

Answer (score 0):

In the context where the button (and its id) are created, bind the id in the o'clock function...

```js
const ids = ['1', '2', '3'];
var parent = document.getElementById('parent')

ids.map(id => {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.setAttribute('id', id)
  btn.innerHTML = `Button ${id}`
  parent.appendChild(btn)
  btn.onclick = event => {
    alert(id)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="parent">
</div>
```